# SOLR Atomic update of custom stored and index metadata clears full-text index

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, full-text-search, atomic

I use bin/post to index all my files in /documents (mounted volume). It works and full-text search works fine.

I do an atomic update for specific metadata that I added to the schema BEFORE posting all docs, it works too.

I do a full-text search to find back the document for which the metadata has been updated, it DOESN'T work anymore, the updates are there but it seems that the full-text index has disappeared.

I do a full re-index and then it overrides my added metadata for the doc, resetting it to the default value. Although the metadata field I added is both stored and indexed.

Not sure what to do. That means that each reindexing will reset my added metadata...not great

Answer (score 0):

The update - under the hood - reconstructs the document from stored fields, applies changes and puts them back to disk. On Lucene level, there is no "document update", it is a higher level concept. That's how the search indexes stay fast in this architecture.

So, your full-text field which is not stored, does not show up in the reconstructed document and does not get stored again in the "updated document".

If you have such a mix of stored and non-stored fields, you have to merge your updates outside of Solr from the original full-content.

Alternatively, depending on your use case, if you are just returning those update values, you could inject them with custom SearchComponent, use ExternalFileField or similar. The user mailing list could be a good place to ask for various options possible.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Let me explain further my case: